# Displaying images from Facebook photo albums on a portfolio site using the graph api

Tags: json, facebook, image-gallery, facebook-graph-api

A client of mine would like to be able to update her site's image galleries by adding images to albums on her facebook account. Is this possible using JSON? would the albums she chose to display need to be made public? Thanks for any help on this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is definitely possible by using the graph api:

Get the ID of all of her albums - select the one you want:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums/

Access the album:

https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos

You need the user_photos permission and the album needs to be public.

This returns you a list of all the photos in the following JSON form:

```
{
          "id": "104988432890979",
                 "from": {
                    "name": "Patrick Snape",
                    "id": "100001394674670"
                 },
                 "picture": "http://photos-f.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc4/hs272.snc4/39934_104988432890979_100001394674670_46790_6171664_s.jpg",
                 "source": "http://sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc4/hs272.snc4/39934_104988432890979_100001394674670_46790_6171664_n.jpg",
                 "height": 540,
                 "width": 720,
                 "link": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=46790&id=100001394674670",
                 "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z2E5Y/hash/8as8iqdm.gif",
                 "created_time": "2010-08-11T10:32:45+0000",
                 "updated_time": "2010-08-11T10:32:47+0000"
              }
}
```

You can then use the source of the photo to get the full sized image

Comment: The <user>/albums URL does not seem to list the "Wall Photos" album ID.  Anyone know why?  Is there another way to get the Wall Photos?

Answer (score 1):

https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/albums/
would get you 25 most recent albums and you must set the 'limit=0' in the url
like

https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/albums/?limit=0
this would get u all the albums...
and also make sure your album 'Wall Photos' is set to public otherwise you'll require 'user_photos' permission.

then you need to get the album id of the album with title 'Wall Photos'
and you can retrieve the photos using that album id

```
$wall_album_id='';
$url = "http://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?fields=id,name&limit=0";
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
foreach($obj->data as $item) {
    if ($item->name == 'Wall Photos'){
            $wall_album_id=$item->id;
            break;
    }
}
```

you can then use the album '$wall_album_id' to get the wall photos...