# Displaying facebook albums in image galleries PART II

Tags: facebook, image-gallery, facebook-graph-api

A few days ago i asked this question: [Displaying images from Facebook photo albums on a portfolio site using the graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732685/displaying-images-from-facebook-photo-albums-on-a-portfolio-site-using-the-graph)

I was basically asking if it was possible to pull images from facebook albums into image galleries on a website, and was very happy to find out it was. Now the next step is to actually parse the information that the graph api returns and display the images on the page using javascript.

i'm having some trouble getting started, and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction. i've havnt really done much dynamic web design (mainly static sites) but i'm getting more into it lately. i assume i will need to utilize JSON or something similar, and i'm a bit over my head.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated. THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this http://www.prettyklicks.com/blog/making-a-facebook-feed-using-the-graph-api-json-and-jquery/291/ tutorial which REALLY cleared things up.

just putting it here in case someone else needs it.